# Flash Animation Assistance Needed

Tags: flash, actionscript, animation

I have a project I'm working on and I am really stumped on making a seemingly simple animation work.

The animation is of a coin scratching off a layer to reveal the layer beneath. I have the coin animated, and the layers in place. I am wanting to know if there is a way to erase/delete every place the coin passes over the stage, revealing the layer beneath. I've seen animations where ActionScript is used to allow a user to control the coin/pointer and activate the "scratch-off" effect. However, I am trying to come up with a method that is not a user-initiated animation since I want the effect to repeat in several places in the timeline.

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to make this work. I am a moderately skilled Flash user and an ActionScript novice.

I am using Flash CS4 on a SnowLeopard Mac.

Any assistance or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the layer you want to reveal *on top* of the layer you want to show to begin with. Then you use a [mask](http://www.google.com/search?q=flash+mask) to reveal the parts you want to. You can animate the mask layer like any other layer, either using a tween or a frame-by-frame animation.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try this. I'd already attempted the frame by frame animation. I placeed the layer that was to be "scratched" off on top of the reveal layer, set it as a graphic symbol and deleted the parts passed over by the coin in each frame, Which was upwards of 90 frames and 90 seperate graphic symbols. It was a mess and I was convinced there had to be an easier way.

Comment: Thanks grapefrukt. That worked. Learned something new today. Now I am trying to tween multiple masks on that layer. The Coin swipes across the stage three times. The first swipe is a mask and works great, but when the coin animation comes back for the second and third pass, the masks start to tween together, like a shape tween. I'm working on that now. Sure it's just something I neglected.
Thanks again.